# How to make REST call to Content-Type="application/json" via VBA in Excel?

Tags: json, vba, rest, excel

I'm using Google Chrome REST API to get information from my web server.
I use: Content-Type = "application/json"
and a **Post** command that includes groovy code inside the **Payload** (the **header** remains empty):

{
    "aaa": "dan",
    "bbb": "my_data",
    "ccc": "my_type"
}

or sometimes the Post is empty also in the Payload

This works just fine (I'm getting the response in json format)

I want to post this command with VBA from excel so the response would get into a VBA variable, which I can then print into some cell in the worksheet. How do I do it?

Do I need to download some library for that?

I tried (without success):

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

URL = "[**my_URL**]"

objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False

objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"

Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1)=objHTTP

Please advise,

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add:
objHTTP.setTimeouts 30000, 60000, 30000, 120000

Comment: please revise your original question to include this information, and remove this "answer" since it is not an answer.

Comment: @DavidZemens If this solves OP's problem then it can be posted as an answer. Why should you add the solution as an edit to the question, even if he answers his own question?

Comment: @Mathias there is no indication that this actually solves the problem.  Perhaps it does, but he does not say so. OP already made one other "answer" which is just a follow-up question to the original question. Without testing, this appeared to be more of the same: just a follow-up comment bereft of any context.  If this is in fact the solution, then he needs to add more detail or preferably, revise his other "answer" to include this.